# Android java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android

Here is how I declared and init my static variable

```
private static final SparseIntArray level2site = new SparseIntArray() {{
    level2site.append(0, 198);
    level2site.append(10010, 199);
    level2site.append(10020, 200);
    level2site.append(10030, 201);
}};
```

And I got this

```
Process: com.chotot.vn.dev, PID: 3104                                                                 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.chotot.vn.property.xiti.PropertyXitiUtils.wrapRegion(PropertyXitiUtils.java:0)
at com.chotot.vn.fragments.AdsFragment.senTagPropertyHomePage(AdsFragment.java:1623)
at                                                com.chotot.vn.fragments.AdsFragment.enableVerticalMode(AdsFragment.java:1606)                  at com.chotot.vn.fragments.AdsFragment.tryEnableVerticalMode(AdsFragment.java:576)
at com.chotot.vn.fragments.AdsFragment.onViewCreated(AdsFragment.java:555)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1132)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:541)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

What is happen here? How can I fix it?

Comment: `com.chotot.vn.property.xiti.PropertyXitiUtils` Is this your code?

Comment: Yes, It is my code.

Comment: Then what is happening at `PropertyXitiUtils.java:0`? All you showed is some random `SparseIntArray`, which is definitely not at the first line of that file.

Comment: Have you tried not using double-brace initialization? Do you know what that really does?

Comment: What happened in `PropertyXitiUtils.java:0` is my code that was posted.

Comment: But the first line would be a package statement or block comment, not that code

Comment: @cricket_007 yea I know but my Android Studio point to this code.

Comment: Points how? What does `AdsFragment.java:1623` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a circular reference to a variable within its own static initialization.

How about this?

```
private static final SparseIntArray level2site = new SparseIntArray() {{
    append(0, 198);
    append(10010, 199);
    append(10020, 200);
    append(10030, 201);
}};
```

Comment: Wow It fixed my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for ExceptionInInitializerError is if something is wrong inside your static initializer block. Here change your code like this

```
private static final SparseIntArray level2site = new SparseIntArray();

{
    level2site.append(0, 198);
    level2site.append(10010, 199);
    level2site.append(10020, 200);
    level2site.append(10030, 201);
}
```

Note that i have put up a semicolon at the end of the declaration, and the rest is inside a block. I executed this code, got no error. And the values are correctly assigned in it.

Printed the data with this code :

```
for(int i = 0; i < level2site.size(); i++) {
        int key = level2site.keyAt(i);
        // get the object by the key.
        Object obj = level2site.get(key);
        System.out.println("SPR    "+obj);
    }
```